# Hierarchical linear model in the context of an experiment

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, experiment-design, nested-data

In an experimental study, I randomly assign participants to one of two conditions: Condition A (which they read Text A), and Condition B (in which they read Text B). After reading their assigned text, participants across conditions complete a measure composed of 9 different items -- 4 items assessing the likelihood of engaging in behaviors of Type 1 (Items #1, #2, #3, #4), and 5 items assessing the likelihood of engaging in behaviors of Type 2 (Items #5, #6, #7 #8, #9). For each behavior, participants indicate their response using a response scale ranging from 1 to 4.

In this research project, I am **not** interested in participants' scores on each individual behavior. Instead, I am interested in their average likelihood of performing Type 1 behaviors vs. Type 2 behaviors (calculated by aggregating their scores across Type 1 and Type 2 items, respectively).

My prediction is that Condition will significantly affect participants' likelihood of performing Type 2 behaviors, but not their likelihood of performing Type 1 behaviors. In other words, I predict a significant Condition x Type interaction effect. I know how to test this prediction using a 2 (Condition: A vs. B) x 2 (Behavior type: Type 1 vs. Type 2) mixed ANOVA with repeated measures on the second factor.

However, I am now seeking to test my prediction using a hierarchical linear model, and I'm having trouble specifying the various levels in the model. Here are my questions:

1. Does the study design described above correspond to a "crossed design"?
2. If so, am I right in thinking that the nested structure looks like this: Item number (Level 1), nested within both Behavior types (Level 2) and Participants (Level 2)? Is it also necessary to include Condition as Level 3, or can I consider it as a Level-2 factor, given it is a between-subject factor?